# PHP: conventional documentation

Tags: php, phpdoc

Изучаю документацию phpDocumentor, где на [первой](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/welcome.html) странице сказано:

> Documentation generated by phpDocumentor 2 does not aim to be a replacement for conventional documentation but is rather supplemental, or reference, documentation.

Что за *обычная (традиционная) документация* и где она описана?

То есть я так понимаю есть другие: традиционные способы документирования кода; но где о них есть информация?

Comment: Нигде. Это просто описание того, что библиотека делает. Это не поддается формализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь имеется в виду традиционная документация к проекту. Диаграммы UML, ERP, функциональное описание, описание для системных администраторов, документация пользователей и т.п. Все то, что позволяет сопровождать и использовать программный продукт. phpDocumentator генерирует документацию из комментариев разработчиков к файлам, классам, методам и переменным. Это не совсем традиционный подход к составлению документации, хотя и он и приобрел большую популярность в последние годы.

Для разработчиков phpDocumentator - стандарт де-факто. Альтернативный проект Docblox, был объединен с phpDocumentator, в результате чего появился phpDocumentator 2.

Более того, в настоящий момент разрабатывается [стандарт PSR-5](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md), посвященный документированию PHP-кода. После того, как он будет принят - он станет обязателен для всех разработчиков фреймворков (по крайней мере тех, которые поддерживают PSR, а это подавляющее большинство сообщества - Yii, Symfony, Laravel). При разработке PSR-5 за основу был взят phpDocumentator. Однако, даже если какие-то отличия появятся, после того как стандарт будет принят, phpDocumentator будет вынужден их реализовать.

Дальнейшие изменения и модификации будут производиться путем разработки новых расширенных стандартов PSR (под новым номером, по аналогии с RFC).